# Angular validation not working when Function name mentioned in HTML

Tags: angular, validation

Angular Validation does not work when I use the valiadation function name in HTML.

If i Remove it, It works.

```
    export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {
    ngOnInit() {
    }
    constructor (private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
        private titleService: Title,
        private _router: Router) {
        this.setTitle('BS - Register New');
    }

    // tslint:disable-next-line: member-ordering
    registerForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup ({
        orgName: new FormControl(null,
        [Validators.required,
        Validators.minLength(5),
        this.checkOrgName
        ] )
    });

    checkOrgName (controls: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null{
        if (controls.value === 'ABCDEF') {
            console.log("Error")
            return {incorrectOrg: 'Company Name can not be ABCDEF'}
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

HTML Code

```
div class="form-group">
        <label for="orgName">Organization Name</label>
        <!-- Name , and formControlName should be same as in ts file  -->
        <input
          name="orgName"
          formControlName="orgName"
          type="text"
          id="orgName"
          placeholder="Organization Name"
          class="form-control"
          autofocus
          [class.is-invalid]="registerForm.get('orgName').invalid &&
                              registerForm.get('orgName').touched">

        <div *ngIf="registerForm.get('orgName').invalid &&
                    registerForm.get('orgName').touched">

          <!-- <small *ngIf="registerForm.get('orgName').errors?.required" -->
          <small *ngIf="registerForm.get('orgName').errors?.required"
                  class="text-danger">
               Organization Name is Required
          </small>

          <small *ngIf="registerForm.get('orgName').errors?.minlength"
                  class="text-danger">
              Organization Name should be more than 5 Characters long
          </small>

          <small

*ngIf="registerForm.controls.orgName.errors?.checkOrgName"
                    class="text-danger">
            {{registerForm.get('orgName').errors['incorrectOrg']}}
          </small>
        </div>
      </div>
```

**In the Above code, validation works but  the error is not displayed,**

**But if i replace "*ngIf="registerForm.controls.orgName.errors?.checkOrgName"  by "*ngIf="registerForm.controls.orgName.errors"  in HTML **

**The error message is displayed successfully.**

Please help me by letting me know what is the mistake in the code if Function name is mentioned in HTML?

Regards,
Ashish

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the `key` of the object you returned from the validator.

So it should be `*ngIf="registerForm.controls.orgName.errors?.incorrectOrg"` in the template.